# Simple calendar in ReactJS and Material Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, material-design

I have to create small simple calendar and attendance list with React and Material-UI. The problem is I am new to React and programming overall so I don't know how to start :/. I know I am rushing my learning process but I recently gain an opportunity to start a practice job in software company and I want to make my best so they can offer my a job.
I have to do following:

1. Create list with workers(attendance list)
2. Create a Calendar
3. When I click on a name, calendar shows if that person was present or not
4. When I click on a date, calendar shows a name, entry and leave time

Worker's list won't be hard but calendar will :/ I don't ask you to do this. I would appreciate if you would show me the hints and maybe few lines of code.

ps. Only react, js, html and css. UI should be based on Maetrial Design. No jQuery or other frameworks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the existing model.

react-big-calendar、react-event-calendar....

You can get them on https://www.npmjs.com/ .

Comment: This got downvoted, but if you need a list of workers, then react-big-calendar might be a decent choice, as it supports the concept of events, which will allow you to include text in each date's block on the calendar. http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#intro

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are number of Material Design widgets. You can check at:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

If you click on the grey heading of each example- it will show you the equivalent React.js code.